# P $\neq$ NP via Time Hierarchy Theorem?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete

The Time Hierarchy Theorem proves that for time-constructible functions, *f(n)*, *g(n)*, if

*f(n)log(f(n)) = o(g(n))*,

then **DTIME(f(n))** $\subsetneq$ **DTIME(g(n))**

So, there will be problems solvable in *g(n)* time, but not in *f(n)* time.

Now, all polynomials are time constructible functions.
And, it is easy to see that

$n^k$*log($n^k$)* = $n^k$.*k*.*log(n) < $n^{k+1}$*

This shows that **P**, the class of decision problems that take polynomial time, is unbounded in the polynomials it requires. As in, there are decision problems in **P** which are unsolvable in time $n^{k}$, but solvable in time $n^{k+1}$.

Considering that **NP**-complete problems are atleast as hard as any problem in **P**, then does this not show that **NP**-complete problems must require exponential time? For, if a **NP**-complete problem does have an algorithm that runs in time $n^k$, then, because of the time hierarchy theorem, it must be weaker than some problems in **P**, which require $n^{k+1}$, or more time to solve.

Comment: "Considering that NP-complete problems are atleast as hard as any problem in P, then does this not show that NP-complete problems must require exponential time?" No. Some problems may take strictly more than every polynomial time and strictly less than every exponential time, consider for example the times $$\exp\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

> Considering that **NP**-complete problems are atleast as hard as any problem in **P**, then does this not show that **NP**-complete problems must require exponential time?

When we say that one problem is at least as hard as another we normally mean this in the sense of [polynomial-time reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction). This means that we can take an instance of one problem and turn it into an instance of the other, *using only polynomially much time*. This shows that second problem is at least as hard as the first (because any instance of the first can be transformed into an instance of the second) but only *up to a polynomial*.

More precisely, the reduction takes a polynomial amount of time, and it can also change the input size by up to a polynomial amount. The degree of these polynomials is not bounded, and so it can be larger than $k$.